# Summing Monthly Data in Excel

Tags: excel

My goal was to create a graph which plotted the number times a type of event occurred each month.

I have data of certain events happening during a given month. My data contains the date of occurrence, a numerical identifier, and the type of event. I have created a pivot tables for each type of event which counts the the number of numerical identifiers per date. So, I basically have two columns, one with the dates and one with the amount of occurrences on each date.

After searching around the internet, I created a table with 1-12 in one column to represent each month, and then the following as an array which fills up another column:

{=SUM(--(MONTH(B) = A))}

Where B is the range of dates for each type of event and A is the month identifier 1-12. So, I end up having data for each month.

At first I thought this would be sufficient, however I just noticed that it is incorrect. The problem is that the arrays only count the number of dates and not the number of occurrences that happen on each date, so I am short a few instances.

There must be a better way to do this, or perhaps a way to have Excel use the number of occurrences each date counted. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a column that contains a number containing occurrences; let's call that column O. Let's also say that your dates are in column D and there a series of incremental numbers from 1 to 12 in Z2:Z13. In AA2 put this *standard* (non-array) formula,

```
=sumproduct((month(D$2:D$999)=Z2)*(O$2:O$999))
```

Adjust the ranges to suit your own data and fill down to AA13.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I knew there was an easier way. Thanks Jeeped!